# Can we revert law of cosines into its original complex identity?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Write for $a$,$b$,$c$ positive and $z=x+iy$ complex:

$$a^z+b^z=c^z$$

This is equivalent to the system:

$$a^x\cos(y\ln(a))+b^x\cos(y\ln(b))=c^x\cos(y\ln(c))$$
$$a^x\sin(y\ln(a))+b^x\sin(y\ln(b))=c^x\sin(y\ln(c))$$

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand. Just food for thought, but the law of cosines states that $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A$. On the other hand in your last system of three equations, you have real exponents, which is different to the law of cosines. Also in the first of those last three equations you have $+2a^xb^x$ and not $-2a^xb^x$.

Comment: in that case you would need that $a^x$, $b^x$ and $c^x$ form the sides of a triangle. I think ultimately your final system relies on the assumption that $a^z+b^z=c^z$. If that assumption does not hold, then your system does not hold. So... in reverse if you assume your system of three equations **does hold** then you should be able to recover $a^z+b^z=c^z$. I would recommend making the assumption your system of three equations is correct, then logically write down the steps to get back to $a^z+b^z=c^z$, making sure each step is legitimate. That would be the proof you are looking for.

Comment: Out of interest, starting with the assumption that your last system holds true, and supposing $z$ is real, i.e. $y=0$, then
$$a^{2x}+b^{2x}+2a^xb^x=c^{2x}\implies (a^x+b^x)^2=(c^x)^2$$
$$c^{2x}+b^{2x}-2c^xb^x=a^{2x}\implies (c^x-b^x)^2=(a^x)^2$$
$$c^{2x}+a^{2x}-2c^xa^x=b^{2x}\implies (c^x-a^x)^2=(b^x)^2$$

Comment: yes exactly. It should be possible to write your argument for all complex numbers in the reverse direction, starting with the assumption that $a^x$, $b^x$, $c^x$ form the sides of a triangle :-D. It may take some time to carefully work through that path, but I've done similar proofs before.